# Subscribe to issue queue

Tags: community-official-site

In drupal.org I would like to get email notification when an issue that involves me is updated with a new comment. Right now I have to subscribe per project from URL http://drupal.org/project/issues/subscribe-mail/[project-name] by clicking "own issues" checkbox. This is pain. Sometimes I fail to subscribe to a project and I get no follow-up comments in email.

Is there a page where I can enable it globally to subscribe to all my own issues as against doing it for individual project ?

Comment: wtf downvote ? I understand that drupal stackexchange is not the right place to post this questions. Initially it was posted to support@drupal.org and it got struck into moderation queue. It is four days since the email was sent and no updates yet. I am motivated to post it here as I always get right answers on time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was a page that would allow you to subscribe to different projects, but it has been removed.
The only way to subscribe to project issue queues is the one you described.

The link to subscribe to the issue queue of a project is present in two places:

- in the project page, in a block to the right side
- in the project issue queue, under the issue queue title

  [image: screenshot]

  [image: screenshot]

Comment: I liked the old way. I subscribed to all products "my issues". It was better than having to remember to subscribe to every new issue queue I get involved with.

Comment: I am already aware of those thanks for confirming it though.